# How to use nested for loops and recursion to create a list of combinations of strings

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a SortedList in Key/Value pair that so far stores 3 entries like this:

```
Key: "Shapes" and Value: ["Cube", "Sphere"]
Key: "Colors" and Value: ["Red", "Green"]
Key: "Sizes" and Value: ["Big", "Small"]
```

My goal is generate all the combination of strings and store them into another list like this:

```
"Shape:Cube/Colors:Red/Size:Big"
"Shape:Cube/Colors:Red/Size:Small"
"Shape:Cube/Colors:Green/Size:Big"
"Shape:Cube/Colors:Green/Size:Small"
"Shape:Sphere/Colors:Red/Size:Big"
"Shape:Sphere/Colors:Red/Size:Small"
"Shape:Sphere/Colors:Green/Size:Big"
"Shape:Sphere/Colors:Green/Size:Small"
```

The caveat here is that there can be N number of entries in the first SortedList so I can't really create the for-loops in my source code before hand. I know I should use recursion to tackle the trickiness of the dynamic N value.

So far I've only come up with a hard-coded solution for N=2 entries and I'm having trouble translating into a recursion that can handle any value of N entries:

```
for (int ns=0; ns < listFeaturesSuperblock.Values[0].Count; ns++) { 
    for (int nc=0; nc < listFeaturesSuperblock.Values[1].Count; nc++) { 

        //prefab to load
        string str = "PreFabs/Objects/" + listFeaturesSuperblock.Keys[0][ns] + ":" + listFeaturesSuperblock.Values[0][ns] + "/" + listFeaturesSuperblock.Values[1][nc] + ":" + listFeaturesSuperblock.Values[1][nc];
    }
}
```

Can somebody kindly point me towards the right direction? How should I approach this and what do I need to study to get better at coding recursion?

Thank you.

Comment: why "nested for loops" **and** "recursion"?

Comment: My logic is that for loops or even while loops allow me to iterate through the list of entries and list of values and I need recursion because I don't know how many entries there will be, so the amount of for loops is based on the size of the original list of entries. @Carsten

Comment: This is a standard problem. Your function, say fillList() will be constructing a new element in the resulting list, step-by-step. It will need one argument - the index of the key/values pair that it is currently considering and the partially constructed string, the new element of the resulting list that it is constructing. It will loop through all values for that key, append one of them to a new copy of the constructed string, and call itself while incrementing the index argument. If it is called with index argument equal to the number of features (length of your list), it appends and returns.

Comment: _there can be N number of entries ... so I can't create the for-loops in my source code before hand_ makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current method:

```
List<string> result = new List<string>;

ProcessItems(listFeaturesSuperblock, result);
```

And this is the recursive method:

```
void ProcessItems(SortedList<string, List<string>> data, List<string> result, int level = 0, string prefix = "PreFabs/Objects/")
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Values[level].Count; i++)
    {
        string item = prefix + data.Keys[level] + ":" + data.Values[level][i] + "/";
        if (level == data.Values.Count - 1)
            result.Add(item);
        else
            ProcessItems(data, result, level + 1, item);
    }
}
```

The 'result' variable will then contain all permutations.

Comment: It should be `data.Keys[level]` and not `data.Keys[level][i]`. And `SortedList<string, List<string>> data` instead of `List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> data`.

Answer (score 1):

To use recursion is quiet a simple way and here's how.

Let's say we have `Dictionary` just like in your example

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> props = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(){
    { "Shapes", new List<string>{"Cube", "Sphere"} },
    { "Colors", new List<string>{"Red", "Green"} },
    { "Sizes", new List<string>{"Big", "Small"} }
};
```

Now we take all values of first key and go through them appending their values to the source string. So for the first value we will get

```
/Shapes:Cube
```

And now we do the same for the next key `Colors`, resulting

```
/Shapes:Cube/Colors:Red
```

We continue it while there are more unprocessed keys. When there are no more keys we got the first result string

```
/Shapes:Cube/Colors:Red/Sizes:Big
```

now we need to go back and add another value which result

```
/Shapes:Cube/Colors:Red/Sizes:Small
```

And the code for this will be like following

```
public static List<string> GetObjectPropertiesPermutations(string src, string[] keys, int index) {
    if(index >= keys.Length) {
        return new List<string>() { src };
    }
    var list = new List<string>();
    var key = keys[index];
    foreach(var val in props[key]) {
        var other = GetObjectPropertiesPermutations(src + "/" + key + ":" + val, keys, index + 1);
        list.AddRange(other);
    }
    return list;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var perms = GetObjectPropertiesPermutations("", props.Keys.ToArray(), 0);
    foreach(var s in perms) {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```